# How can I keep the same side of a box perpendicular to the camera location in povray?

Tags: vector, normals, povray

I have a box object in povray defined by two 3 dimensional vectors.  V1 specifies the top left of the box while V2 is the bottom right of the box.  On one of the sides of the box is a jpeg.  I am trying to figure out how to rotate the box when the camera location changes, so that the side of the box with the jpeg is always perpendicular to the location of the camera.  The "look at" vector will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a transform that you apply to both your box and the camera.

```
#declare your_box= box{V1,V2,pigment{*etc.* }}

#declare some_transform=transform{*rotate translate, etc.*}

#object{your_box
transform{some_transform}
}

camera{*settings that point it perfectly at your box*
transform{some_transform}}
```

Comment: This will not work. E.g. translations of object and camera are independent from each other. The rotation of the object depends on the location of the camera. A normal vector of the object has to point towards the camera. I will try something ...